# $Z_n$ is a group. what is meant addition or multiplication? how about the units?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $Z_n$ is a group.  what is meant addition or multiplication? how about the units?

---

Guessing anytime $Z_n$ is given as a group its addition.

Anytime units  group then multiplication is the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Bbb Z_n$ is a group under addition.

The corresponding group under multiplication is $(\Bbb Z_n)^*$.

One important difference is that the former contains $0$ while the latter doesn't.

Comment: 0 times the other elements would just make alot of zeros on a row or column and would not be a group under mult of $z_n$

Comment: Correct.$ $$ $$ $